# Basic inserting data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm a newbie in Visual Studio and I want to make a database system that allows the user to insert, update, delete and search data using a Windows Forms application.

I already watched 3 tutorial how but I'm getting the same error. when I delete my `ExecuteNonQuery()` call, it doesn't have any error but the data I entered into my textboxes is not inserted into my database. When I put it back I'm getting this kind of error

[ERROR:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xKyF.png)

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EaglePlannersDatabase
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\EaglePlannersDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into EAGLEPLANNERS(policy number,plan type,renewal date,name,age,address,birthday,email,home/office number,mode of payment,amount) values (@policy number,@plan type,@renewal date,@name,@age,@address,@birthday,@email,@home/office number,@mode of payment,@amount)", connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policy number", int.Parse(policyNumbertxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plan type", planTypetxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@renewal date", int.Parse(renewalDatetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nametxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", int.Parse(agetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addresstxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", int.Parse(birthdaytxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", (emailtxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@home/office number", int.Parse(homeofficetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode of payment", (modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", int.Parse(amounttxtbox.Text));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            policyNumbertxtbox.Text = "";
            planTypetxtbox.Text = "";
            renewalDatetxtbox.Text = "";
            nametxtbox.Text = "";
            agetxtbox.Text = "";
            addresstxtbox.Text = "";
            birthdaytxtbox.Text = "";
            emailtxtbox.Text = "";
            homeofficetxtbox.Text = "";
            modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text = "";
            amounttxtbox.Text = "";

            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Query has errors Do not use "home/office number" instead name your column as "homeOfficeNumber" and if you absolutely want to use "home/office number" then put brackets on each side like "[home/office number]"

Comment: "mode of payment" is wrong if you want spaces then you need to put brackets "[mode of payment]"

Comment: Just rename your columns and remove spaces and special characters from your database column names

Comment: hello thanks for your answer I'm getting this new error now that System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@policy".'

Comment: change your database column name "policy number" to PolicyNumber AND "@policy number" to @PolicyNumber in your query too and in parameter too

Comment: All your ColumnNames and @VariableNames Must match

Comment: remove spaces and special characters from database column and queries

Comment: thank you for your time. I already removed and did what you said and i think it fixed the problem. I'm having a new error says that "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'tbl1'.'"

Comment: i changed my table name EAGLEPLANNERS into tbl1 but still getting this error

Comment: As @MuhammadWaqasAziz said, you need to rename columns name values instead of renaming table name, so if you have home/office number column name value, that need to be changed for example to home_office_number or something like that

Comment: @Jakobson I already changed all of that then when I tried to run the program it comes with another error that says System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'tbl1'.'

Comment: I changed my database column name also similar

Comment: what is the name of your table in your database?

Comment: These are basic syntax errors I'd expect a student to be able to resolve :(

Comment: By the way you should not cache the connection object. Create it when you need it and dispose with `using`

Answer (score 0):

here's my new code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EaglePlannersDatabase
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\EaglePlannersDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            
            
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"Insert Into tbl1 
( PolicyNumber,
  planType,
  renewalDate,
  name,
  age,
  address,
  birthday,
  email,
  homeOfficeNumber,
  modeOfPayment,
  amount ) 
values 
( @PolicyNumber,
  @planType,
  @renewalDate,
  @name,
  @age,
  @address,
  @birthday,
  @email,
  @homeOfficeNumber,
  @modeOfPayment,
  @amount )", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber", int.Parse(policyNumbertxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planType", planTypetxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@renewalDate", int.Parse(renewalDatetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nametxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", int.Parse(agetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addresstxtbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", int.Parse(birthdaytxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", (emailtxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeOfficeNumber", int.Parse(homeofficetxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modeOfPayment", (modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", int.Parse(amounttxtbox.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            policyNumbertxtbox.Text = "";
            planTypetxtbox.Text = "";
            renewalDatetxtbox.Text = "";
            nametxtbox.Text = "";
            agetxtbox.Text = "";
            addresstxtbox.Text = "";
            birthdaytxtbox.Text = "";
            emailtxtbox.Text = "";
            homeofficetxtbox.Text = "";
            modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text = "";
            amounttxtbox.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

here's my database
[image: database]

Comment: Your database name is wrong i think

Comment: Why are you using AttachDbFilename in the connection string? Are you sure that's the same database you are working with in the designer? You should just connect to the localdb instance, not attach an mdf file. Also, you should edit your question instead of writing an answer to provide new information

Comment: Your connection string is quite strange , specify your database in connection string where table is located with InitialCatalog so just add attribute Initial Catalog=databasename; in your connection string

Comment: @Crowcoder I just copied the connection string of my database in the properties window into my connectrion string line of code. was that the wrong way of connecting the database into my system?

Comment: @Jakobson I did what you said and I'm not getting any more errors but the data I putted in my textboxes to be inserted into my database is not being inserted as it should be. it is not working still

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename

Comment: Have you checked with debugger what are the values that will be stored into the table ? Just put the breakpoint on the line where your insert query start, and step into the code to check if you have any value, maybe imho is better way before creating command object, to create variables where you will store the values of your textboxes, and after that just add that variable as parameter, so for example, int age = Convert.ToInt32(agetxtbox.Text) , and after that you can add that variable as parameter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the possible answer on your question, what I have done here, first I changed your connection string by removing `AttachDbFilename` attribute, and replace that by adding of `Initial Catalog` attribute where I set the name of your database.
Next thing, I declared variables where the values from textboxes will be stored, these values of variables will be our parameters, this is not necessary to do, it is just my own style, you can keep as you done.
I have seen also, that you are not using `try/catch/finally` block and you are closing the connection in the same part of code where you opening the connection, and maybe that is the reason why your values are not being stored into the table, so I decided to round your code within that block. If you don't know what  is try/catch/finally block you can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) .   We are opening the connection and do all operations on database in try block, in catch block we are catching all errors that might be caused in our application and in finally we are closing the connection. You will also notice that I created additional check, where I checking the result of `ExecuteNonQuery()` method, and if result of ExecuteNonQuery method is equals to 1 - records is inserted successfully, otherwise it fails.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace EaglePlannersDatabase
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=EaglePlannersDataBase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int policyNumber = Convert.ToInt32(policyNumbertxtbox.Text);
                string planType = planTypetxtbox.Text;
                int renewalDate = Convert.ToInt32(renewalDatetxtbox.Text);
                string name = nametxtbox.Text;
                int age = Convert.ToInt32(agetxtbox.Text);
                string address = addresstxtbox.Text;
                int birthday = Convert.ToInt32(birthdaytxtbox.Text);
                string email = emailtxtbox.Text;
                int homeOfficeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(homeofficetxtbox.Text);
                string modeOfPayment = modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text;
                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(amounttxtbox.Text);
                
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl1 (PolicyNumber,planType,renewalDate,name,age,address,birthday,email,homeOfficeNumber,modeOfPayment,amount) values (@PolicyNumber,@planType,@renewalDate,@name,@age,@address,@birthday,@email,@homeOfficeNumber,@modeOfPayment,@amount)", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber",policyNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planType",planType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@renewalDate",renewalDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age",age);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",address);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday",birthday);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeOfficeNumber",homeOfficeNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modeOfPayment",modeOfPayment);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount",amount);
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(result == 1)
                    {
                    
                        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully!");
                        policyNumbertxtbox.Text = "";
                        planTypetxtbox.Text = "";
                        renewalDatetxtbox.Text = "";
                        nametxtbox.Text = "";
                        agetxtbox.Text = "";
                        addresstxtbox.Text = "";
                        birthdaytxtbox.Text = "";
                        emailtxtbox.Text = "";
                        homeofficetxtbox.Text = "";
                        modeofpaymenttxtbox.Text = "";
                        amounttxtbox.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
                    }
                }
                catch(SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("We have found error with operation on database: " + ex.Message);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("We have found error in your code: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie, getting the pieces working first, then applying to the user interface I would apply second. I will try to summarize each piece.  First your connection itself looked strange as others have pointed out.  I would try to first make sure the connection itself works before applying any attempt at sql insert/update/delete going on.  So you might try

```
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
@"Data Source (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\EaglePlannersDataBase.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30" );

private void TestConnect()
{
   if( connection.Open() )
      // great, you have a good connection
      connection.Close();
   else
      // message to yourself why a failed connection and fix it...
}
```

Once you know your connection is good, then on to your sql-insert.  Having good column names is important.  Dont try to be fancy with human readable with spaces types of column names, just causes headaches.  Use simple and direct as others have pointed out in prior comments.  Also, when parameterizing, I have tried to always slightly alter the insert/update/delete parameters with a "p" prefix indicating the PARAMETER FOR the column, such as

```
insert into SomeTable ( oneColumn, secondCol ) values ( @pOneColumn, @pSecondCol )
```

just to avoid bad confusion.  If an error comes out via "oneColumn" vs "pOneColumn" in the message, you KNOW which thing is at fault.  The column itself does not work, or the specific parameter/value being supplied.

Next, readability of your SQL statements, especially as they get longer.  Use spaces and I typically use a leading "@" before the quoted sql command to allow for line continuations as I edited your previous answer.  So the same above insert would be written more like

```
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"insert into SomeTable
 ( oneColumn,
   secondCol
 )
 values
 ( @pOneColumn,
   @pSecondCol
  )", connection );
```

So if you ever needed to add additional columns (or remove), you can see the paired set of insert columns vs parameters much easier.

Now the testing.  Don't try to work off some user-entered values, put in known VALID values so you dont have to worry about user entered values.  Get the command to WORK, then pull values from interface later.  (continuing from above sample)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pOneColumn", 17 );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSecondCol", "some Text");
```

Then try to execute that and make sure IT works.  Once it does, THEN start pulling from your user interface

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pOneColumn", int.Parse( yourTextControl.Text ));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSecondCol", anotherTextControl.Text );
```

Find your mistakes BEFORE you let any human interaction get into and screw-up the rest of what you think SHOULD work.

Note, if you make public properties to your view models such as

```
public int someAge {get; set;}
```

and then set the bindings of the data entry control in the screen to this `someAge` property, it will only allow a numeric entry to be entered and will otherwise have a value of zero if someone tries to put in text.  Similarly if you are dealing with dates, and if date/time, always use datetime fields for querying purposes vs formatted date as a text field.  You will thank yourself in the future when querying for things within date range periods.  HTH

Finally,[try to avoid using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).  Instead, properly identify the expected data type as described in the linked article.  I just left original context to your code for testing and debug researching purposes.